# Firebase iOS FQuery by child value is failing intermittently

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am using Firebase iOS framework. Don't see an obvious way to tell the build version I am using. I am testing on an iOS simulator usually.

I implemented a helper function to find certain data by indexed key. I have created indexes on these keys in the security rules, but that should not be necessary. My data and query are very similar to the dinosaur query by height example in the firebase docs. My data is flattened to //{key: value, key: value, ...}. E.g., Player/-JwISoamh_jRhYeKvKLk will contain a dictionary like:
 {
   "height": "1.89",
   "firstName": "LeBron",
   "lastName": "James"
 }

I use my code to find all players with lastName === "James". So, in the code below the ObjBase would point to /Player and childKey = "lastName" and value="James". I expect querySnaphot to contain 1 child with the node for "JwISoamh_jRhYeKvKLk".

Even though the data is in my test data in my app on firebaseio.com and the values match up, this code returns me a querySnapshot.childrenCount == 0:

```
FQuery *query = [[objBase queryOrderedByChild:childKey] queryEqualToValue:value];
[query observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *querySnapshot) {
```

Until I change the FEventTypeValue to FEventTypeChildAdded. At that point I get data, but it is not an array of nodes in the querySnapshot.children, but values. As soon as I change the code back to FEventTypeValue my query, exactly as it was before, will work for some period of time (multiple runs of the app). Possibly it stops working when I nuke the data for a bunch of new changes. Maybe it is being cached locally after that initial load.

Perfectly willing to believe I am doing something wrong, but I cannot see what and the fact that it works after I "seed it" with the ChildAdded leads me to think it is an async issue or some initial setup I need to do.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your code and data all look good. Have you tried logging/printing your objBase, childKey and value variables for each run? Maybe one of those is loosing scope or not being populated hence a result of childCount = 0.

Comment: Yes, all the data looked good and valid. It *looks* like it is a data caching issue. Like the child value query needs the data loaded first.